# Basis and Linear Independence definitions

Tags: linear-algebra

There's something I don't understand about basis.

B is a basis of a space V if:

- B is linearly independent.
- B spans V

There is also a fact the B is linearly dependent  if you can write one vector as a linear combination of the other.

In addition, I know that every vector in the vector space is a linear combination of this set.

I don't understand how these facts can be true together? If you can write one vector as a linear combination of the other, isn't it dependent?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Think about $i$ and $j$ as a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. $i$ is not a linear combination of $j$

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your confusion correctly, this should resolve it. You have a slight misunderstanding of the definitions. I will assume that we are dealing with a finite dimensional vector space $V$, for simplicity. If a list of vectors $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis for the space, then $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ satisfies two conditions:

$1)$ Linear Independence: 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i=0\implies a_i=0\:\forall 1\le i\le n,$$
where the $a_i\in \mathbb{F}$, the base field for the vector space. Equivalently, we can reformulate this as saying no basis vector $v_i$ can be represented as 
$$ \sum_{j=1,j\ne i}^na_jv_j=v_i.$$
Next, we have the second condition.

$2)$ Spanning: If $v\in V$, then
$$ v=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$$
where each $v_i$ is one of the basis vectors, and the $a_i$ are appropriately chosen scalars.

Now, these definitions are not contradictory precisely because each basis vector can be represented as $1$ times itself. That is
$$ v_i=1*v_i.$$

The contrast here is that it is **not** the case that a basis vector can be written as a linear combination of the **other** basis vectors, only as a trivial linear combination of **itself.**

Answer (score 1):

Linear dependence/independence is a property of an "array" of $k$ vector.

- If the array is the sequence of the $n$ vectors of the basis then it is independent.
- If the array is the sequence of the $n$ vectors of the basis plus another vector $v$ of the space (therefore an array of $n+1$ vectors) it is dependent, this includes the case of $v$ being equal to one vector of the basis repeated another time

Does it clarify something?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $n$ vectors are linearly independent if $a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n=0$ $\Rightarrow$ that $a_1=....=a_n=0$. A basis of vector space of dimension $n$ is given by $n$ vectors linearly independent.

Comment: Please see my edit from the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

That's because only two of the three statements are true!

The wrong one is:

> "I know that a vector in a basis can be represented as a linear combination of the other vectors in the basis."

That is exactly what you want to avoid in a basis: A basis should span the vector space, which means that you can create any vector living in that vector space by linearly combining the basis-vectors, but we don't care about redundant basis-vectors, i.e., if one of the vectors in the basis can be constructed by some of the other ones, we throw that first one out, since we don't need it to be able to create all vectors in that space.